# Getting prevalue id from umbraco dropdown list

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm currently trying to implement `AJAX` results filtering on a certain page.

I created the dropdowns(on the client side), so that they have the `umbraco` prevalue id as their value.

I will then send this id to the server, rather than the text value. Then I loop through my content to find items with this same id.

The problem, however, is that I can't figure out *how to get the value id from the property*. Everything either returns the text value, or just a 0 value.

This is being performed in an `ApiController`.

These are all of the options I've tried:

```
IPublishedContent root = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First();
var downloads = root.Children.Where(q => q.Name == "Downloads").SingleOrDefault();

foreach (var item in downloads.Children)
{
  var test = item.GetPropertyValue<int>("classification");
  var testing = item.GetProperty("classification");
  var testVal = testing.DataValue;
  var testValToo = testing.GetValue<int>();
  var testThree = testing.Value;
}
```

These are the results in order:

```
 - 0 
 - IPublishedProperty 
 - "textValue" 
 - 0 
 - "textValue"
```

Is it possible to get the selected value id from a dropdownlist property? Or is string matching my only option to compare values?

EDIT:
Nevermind, found the solution. Posting the answer here, in case someone else needs it.

I was using the data type dropdownlist. I should have been using dropdownlist:publishing keys.
dropdownlist only ever returns a value. dropdownlist:publishing keys, however, returns the prevalue id, rather than the text value.

[Source](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/using-umbraco/backoffice-overview/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/Dropdown-Publish-Keys)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps.

```
library.GetPreValueAsString(node.GetProperty<int>("sectionType")).ToLower()
```